How to remove blank pages created before and after a certain pages in thesis writing?
I am writing my PhD thesis in mathematics.
I have used the following preamble:
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage[centertags]{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{newlfont}
\usepackage{xthesis} 
\usepackage{xtocinc} 
%\usepackage[dvips]{graphics}
\usepackage{epsfig}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage[active]{srcltx}
\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}
%\usepackage{pdfpages}
%\usepackage{tocloft}
%\usepackage{titletoc}
\usepackage{anyfontsize}
%\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{cite}




\renewcommand\theadalign{bc}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\bfseries}
\renewcommand\theadgape{\Gape[1pt]}
\renewcommand\cellgape{\Gape[0.1pt]}

\newlength{\defbaselineskip}
\setlength{\defbaselineskip}{\baselineskip}
\newcommand{\setlinespacing}[1]%
           {\setlength{\baselineskip}{#1 \defbaselineskip}}
\newcommand{\doublespacing}{\setlength{\baselineskip}%
                           {2.0 \defbaselineskip}}
\newcommand{\singlespacing}{\setlength{\baselineskip}{\defbaselineskip}}
% MATH -------------------------------------------------------------------
\newcommand{\be}{\begin{equation}}
\newcommand{\ee}{\end{equation}}
\newcommand{\bea}{\begin{eqnarray}}
\newcommand{\eea}{\end{eqnarray}}
\newcommand{\beb}{\begin{eqnarray*}}
\newcommand{\df}{Definition}
\newcommand{\eeb}{\end{eqnarray*}}
\newcommand{\A}{{\cal A}}
\newcommand{\h}{{\cal H}}
\newcommand{\s}{{\cal S}}
\newcommand{\W}{{\cal W}}
\newcommand{\BH}{\mathbf B(\cal H)}
\newcommand{\KH}{\cal  K(\cal H)}
\newcommand{\Real}{\mathbb R}
\newcommand{\Complex}{\mathbb C}
\newcommand{\Field}{\mathbb F}
\newcommand{\RPlus}{[0,\infty)}
%
\newcommand{\norm}[1]{\left\Vert#1\right\Vert}
\newcommand{\essnorm}[1]{\norm{#1}_{\text{\rm\normalshape ess}}}
\newcommand{\abs}[1]{\left\vert#1\right\vert}
\newcommand{\set}[1]{\left\{#1\right\}}
\newcommand{\seq}[1]{\left<#1\right>}
\newcommand{\eps}{\varepsilon}
\newcommand{\To}{\longrightarrow}
\newcommand{\RE}{\operatorname{Re}}
\newcommand{\IM}{\operatorname{Im}}
\newcommand{\Poly}{{\cal{P}}(E)}
\newcommand{\EssD}{{\cal{D}}}
%\usepackage[linktocpage=true]{hyperref}

% THEOREMS ---------------------------------------------------------------
\theoremstyle{plain}
\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{cor}[thm]{Corollary}
\newtheorem{lem}[thm]{Lemma}
\newtheorem{prop}[thm]{Proposition}
\newtheorem{exmp}{Example}[section]
%
\theoremstyle{remark}
\newtheorem{remark}[thm]{Remark}
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{defn}{Definition}[section]
%
\theoremstyle{remark}
\newtheorem{rem}{Remark}[section]
%
\numberwithin{equation}{section}
%%% ----------------------------------------------------------------------
\setlength{\tclineskip}{1.05\baselineskip}
%%% ----------------------------------------------------------------------


\begin{document}

\include{titlepage}
\include{dedicate}
\include{decl}
\include{ACK}
\include{cert-sup}
\parskip 10pt   % 1.5 spacing for contents, etc.

\include{paper}


**\pagenumbering{roman}
\tableofcontents**


\afterpreface
\def\baselinestretch{1}
\setlinespacing{1.66}
% ------------------------------------------------------------------------
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\renewcommand{\theequation}{\arabic{equation}}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}[section]
\newtheorem{lemma}{Lemma}[section]
\newtheorem{proposition}[theorem]{Proposition}
\newtheorem{res}{Result}
\newtheorem{ex}{Example}[section]
\typeout{Preliminaries}
%\include{preliF}

\include{Notation} 

\setlinespacing{1.7}
\renewcommand{\theequation}{\thesection.\arabic{equation}}

\setlinespacing{1.5}
\bibliographystyle{amsplain}
\bibliography{xbib}
\begin{thebibliography}{99}
\baselineskip=15pt
\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}

problem: I have compiled the above preamble, the table of contents as follows:

I just want to start the page numbering from the Notation and Symbol page, but in the current setting/preamble above, I see the "table of contents" itself appearing in the index list. How do I remove it?
Can you please check the preamble, especially, the table of content command above?
Thanks

Why \include and not \input? Oh, the command \cal has been deprecated for about 30 years.

@egreg, i took this preamble from someone. I have checked replacing by \input{}, but still same problem, two blank pages are being created. Only for the "Notation" page, rest other file inclusion are ok

Nobody but you can compile this to test. Comment stuff out before the include until you figure out what is going on. Otherwise, provide a minimal example we can compile to reproduce the issue. \rm has also been deprecated for decades, too. i took this preamble from someone: there's the start of your problems.

@cfr, I solved the blank page problem. The Notation-page had a lot of content, which is why two blank pages were automatically created.  But I need to solve a second problem, that is the table of contents. I want the indexing start from "Notation and Symbol" page

The same comments apply. Edit your question so people have something we can work with if you need help. I'm not sure what you mean by indexing. Not, I suspect, indexing ;).

@cfr, I mean by indexin, the list of contents. If you see in the pdf output, at page i, we have Table of Contents, then at page 2, we have Notation and Symbol, then at page 4, we have Introduction` etc. This is the indexing I meant. Now I want to remove the 1st indexing at page i

It is just that 'indexing' means \makeindex, \index{word} etc. so it is a bit confusing to use the term for the contents ;). But, as I say, you're the only person who can troubleshoot this so long as you're the only person who can reproduce it.

@cfr, anyway, in the table of content, I want to start from Notation and Symbol chapter . I just request that you look at that part (i.e., \tableofcontents) in the above code, if I wrote those in the in the correct way or not.

Why do you think we say that questions should include Minimal Working Examples we can compile to reproduce issues? Because most of the time we can't diagnose problems by reading a bloated preamble and figuring out what effect it will have. Sometimes, people can pinpoint issues if they've come across them before and remember; mostly not. By default the ToC is not included in the ToC. Hence, your code is responsible for changing that default. Sorry, but I'm not randomly reading package docs because you consider an MWE too much trouble. Don't ping me again unless you edit to provide one, please.

@cfr, I am writing every individual chapters in separate way and using \include{filename}, so how can I add those files here. If it was a single latex article,, then I could have given a minimal example

@learner you can use lipsum or blindtext packages to insert dummy text.

Sorry. Since you aren't new, I assumed you'd be directed to this before, but perhaps not. See I've just been asked to write a minimal example, what is that? orWhat makes a good MWE? for advice.

Actually, forget the second link. The first one is much better for your case.

@AndreyL., thanks
